# getInitialState called again after form submit

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have the following test code

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">

        var InputText = React.createClass({
            handleSubmit: function (query) {
                var q = document.getElementById("qval").value;
                console.dir("Query submitted " + q);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/hello",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        this.setState({data: data});
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                        alert("error" + status + " dd " + err.toString());
                        console.error(status, err.toString());
                    }
                });
            },
            getInitialState: function() {
                return{data: "ask a question"};
            },
            render: function() {
                const val = this.state.data;
                console.log("data is " + val);
                return (
                        <div>
                        <form  className="inputText" onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <input type="text" id="qval" value = "" placeholder="ask a question"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                            {this.state.data}
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });
        var element = React.createElement(InputText);
        React.render(element,document.getElementById("content"));

    </script>
</body>
```

What I am finding is that after my ajax call executes, in the render function val prints the response from the server, and then the default value (ask a question). Looks like getInitialState is being called again for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: are you sure your page isn't refreshing? you should call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the web browser from making a request which is the default behavior of the form when sent (`event` is the first argument of your `handleSubmit` callback)

Comment: Doh! that was really stupid. Thanks for pointing it out.